# How to determine if a YouTube video is age restricted, programmatically?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, parental-control

Context: I am developing a firefox/waterfox extension to completely block the "age restricted" videos on youtube, even if the user is logged into his google account.

My question is: 
is there any meta tag or any meta data in the dom of the webpage that indicate the the video is age restricted ?

(PS: note that if I am logged in my google/youtube account, the user message "age restricted" does not appear and the video start to play, si I cannot trigger the blocking on such message).

(PPS: I know about safe mode and moderate mode which can be forced in the DNS server by using a CNAME and this is not the solution thant am looking for, because in moderate mode I can see the videos anyway if I log in my account, assuming that my age is more than 18 in my account, and even if it's true or false I reality)

(PPPS: I guess it would be possible also to catch the flag in some kind of firewall...)

Answer (score 0):

Check the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos). You should make a request and get `contentDetails.contentRating` property. [Here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#usage) you can try it.

Example:
I did request for `id=dQw4w9WgXcQ` ([video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ)) and got this response.

```
/**
 * API response
 */
{
  "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
  "etag": "\"XI7nbFXulYBIpL0ayR_gDh3eu1k/WCks3sFr0-ahtFX4YHD50asKKJo\"",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 1,
    "resultsPerPage": 1
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#video",
      "etag": "\"XI7nbFXulYBIpL0ayR_gDh3eu1k/9el1_iLCMxskRnVNskP6Kr8atag\"",
      "id": "dQw4w9WgXcQ",
      "contentDetails": {
        "duration": "PT3M33S",
        "dimension": "2d",
        "definition": "hd",
        "caption": "false",
        "licensedContent": true,
        "regionRestriction": {
          "allowed": [
            "HK",
            "HN",
            "HM",
            "TH",
            "SH",
            "WF",
            "TG",
            "SI",
            "TF",
            "HR",
            "HU",
            "HT",
            "IS",
            "TC",
            "PS",
            "PR",
            "IL",
            "IM",
            "IN",
            "IO",
            "PY",
            "ID",
            "IE",
            "PA",
            "PG",
            "PF",
            "PE",
            "KW",
            "PK",
            "IQ",
            "IR",
            "PH",
            "IT",
            "PN",
            "PM",
            "PL",
            "AD",
            "AE",
            "AF",
            "AG",
            "AI",
            "YT",
            "AM",
            "AO",
            "AQ",
            "AR",
            "AS",
            "AT",
            "AU",
            "AW",
            "AX",
            "AZ",
            "YE",
            "NP",
            "NR",
            "NU",
            "UY",
            "UZ",
            "AL",
            "NZ",
            "RO",
            "US",
            "NA",
            "UM",
            "NC",
            "NE",
            "NG",
            "NF",
            "NI",
            "UG",
            "NL",
            "NO",
            "FI",
            "FK",
            "FJ",
            "FM",
            "FO",
            "SV",
            "RE",
            "ST",
            "FR",
            "OM",
            "JP",
            "KN",
            "VU",
            "VI",
            "VN",
            "VA",
            "VC",
            "KM",
            "VE",
            "VG",
            "GF",
            "GG",
            "GD",
            "GE",
            "GB",
            "GA",
            "GN",
            "GL",
            "GM",
            "KP",
            "GH",
            "GI",
            "GW",
            "GT",
            "GU",
            "GR",
            "GS",
            "GP",
            "GQ",
            "GY",
            "SJ",
            "LV",
            "LU",
            "LT",
            "SN",
            "LR",
            "SL",
            "SM",
            "SB",
            "SC",
            "SA",
            "SG",
            "LY",
            "SE",
            "SZ",
            "RU",
            "SX",
            "SY",
            "LC",
            "LB",
            "LA",
            "SR",
            "SS",
            "LK",
            "LI",
            "DO",
            "DM",
            "KY",
            "DK",
            "DJ",
            "DZ",
            "JO",
            "MT",
            "MU",
            "MV",
            "MW",
            "MP",
            "MQ",
            "MR",
            "MS",
            "TW",
            "TV",
            "TT",
            "MX",
            "TR",
            "MZ",
            "MD",
            "ME",
            "SD",
            "MG",
            "TK",
            "MA",
            "LS",
            "MC",
            "ML",
            "MM",
            "MN",
            "MO",
            "MH",
            "MK",
            "PW",
            "EH",
            "QA",
            "EE",
            "EG",
            "EC",
            "ET",
            "ER",
            "ES",
            "JE",
            "TD",
            "BY",
            "BZ",
            "JM",
            "BT",
            "BW",
            "BV",
            "BQ",
            "BS",
            "BR",
            "BM",
            "BL",
            "BO",
            "BN",
            "BI",
            "BH",
            "BJ",
            "BE",
            "BD",
            "BG",
            "BF",
            "BA",
            "TZ",
            "ZW",
            "PT",
            "UA",
            "SO",
            "ZA",
            "ZM",
            "BB",
            "CX",
            "CY",
            "KG",
            "KE",
            "CR",
            "KH",
            "KI",
            "CV",
            "CW",
            "CU",
            "KR",
            "CK",
            "CH",
            "CI",
            "CN",
            "CO",
            "CL",
            "CM",
            "KZ",
            "CC",
            "RW",
            "CA",
            "CF",
            "CG",
            "RS",
            "CD",
            "TO",
            "TN",
            "WS",
            "MF",
            "TL",
            "TM",
            "MY",
            "TJ"
          ]
        },
        "projection": "rectangular"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```